# Kendo Virtual ComboBox: selected dataItem is null and is not diplayed in bar, but it is exists in the datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, virtualization, telerik-mvc, kendo-combobox

After reading the documentation, I still have problems trying to implement a simple virtual combo box with only front end values. the combo box displays all my values correctly, and the virtualization works, but when I select an item from the drop down, it does not appear in the combo box "bar".

Here is the basic code:

```
Html
<select role="listbox" id="comboBoxId"></select>

javascript
var comboboxVar = $("#comboBoxId").kendoComboBox({
    placeholder: "select...",
    dataTextField: "DisplayName",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataSource: {
       data: [{DisplayName: "name", Id: "id"}]
     },
    virtual: {
       itemHeight: 26
     }
});
```

After some debugging, I found that, when clicking on the drop down option, the dataItem selected is null. Nonetheless, I am not quire sure why.

I also experimented with the valueMapper method. After some reaserch, I found that if the drop down has no initial values and "value" is not used, it is not necessary to include the method valueMapper. I think the aforementioned scenario is applicable to my situation, but I am not sure if I still have to include the method.

I am using IE to debug, and I am using this code in a Visual Studio MVC web application

Thank you for your help